# I want to learn English, once and for all

Tags: verbs, learning-methods

I can speak or put some words together but there are still a lot of words I don't know. The English we study at school is 'poor' and we do nothing than just talk with the teacher about her trips and that she has been all over the world, which is boring and I'm learning literally nothing from these lessons. I want to speak well but I still can't move to an English speaking country. I want to write well but i can't find some books that can help me improve. So, if you can tell me which books to read in order to improve then it would be great, also some websites with exercises and grammar rules too. By the end of the year I need to be able to write like an Oxford teacher.
Thanks.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97124/tips-for-easy-to-read-unabridged-english-fiction-for-language-learners

Comment: Your writing seems great, so it is not that bad. You just need to have some patience to learn and develop your level to achieve that **goal**. And why don't you learn English in _the_ creative way? There are many channels on YouTube that offer free lessons for English learners.

Answer (score 1):

I think your goal is a bit unrealistic, to be honest. It takes years to become an Oxford teacher, so I'd suggest you start with setting realistic goals for yourself. Read books, listen to music, watch movies, etc. There are lots of free grammar books you can download and channels on YouTube, like Tasneem says. But I'm afraid the only way to really learn a language is to spend some time in a country where the language is spoken. There are so many nuances to any language, you won't learn those from books. Good luck!